# preg_split to unknown number of list() elements

Tags: php, preg-split

I have a PHP script that I wrote probably 10 years ago. I don't remember what version PHP was on at the time but my script worked just fine without complaint from the interpreter. Now, I've had to move my scripts to a new web host and, under PHP 7.x, the interpreter complains loudly about a certain line of this script and I'm looking for an elegant way to get it to shut up.

The offending line is:-

```
list($degrees, $minutes, $seconds) = preg_split("/ /", $coord);
```

The `$coord` variable contains a GPS coordinate in one of three forms: "degrees minutes seconds", "degrees decimal-minutes", or "decimal-degrees". So, the `preg_split()` may return 1, 2, or 3 elements. If it returns only 1 or 2 elements, the interpreter complains loudly about the undefined references to `$seconds` and/or `$minutes`. I see that there is a LIMIT parameter that I could specify for `preg_split()` that gives it a maximum number of elements to return but there doesn't seem to be a complimentary parameter to tell it the MINIMUM number of elements to return. Any suggestions welcome.

Sample coords: '-97.74019' or '-97 44.411' or '-97 44 24.7'

Comment: Why not using `array`?

Comment: `$d_m_s_array = preg_split("/ /", $coord); $degrees = 0; $minutes=0; $seconds=0; if (!empty($d_m_s[0])){$degrees = $d_m_s[0];} ... same for minute and second`

Comment: can you show us a sample value  of `$coord`?

Comment: Use this: `@list($degrees, $minutes, $seconds) = preg_split("/ /", $coord);` See my answer for details.

Comment: unclerojelio  you have answers below,check them and mark+up-vote one answer as accepted.You can up-vote others also if they are useful too.Thanks

Comment: Thanks all. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Totally agree with Anant, but you can do it in bit more elegant way:

```
<?php

$coordArray = preg_split('/ /', $coord);
$degrees = $coordArray[0] ?? 0;
$minutes = $coordArray[1] ?? 0;
$seconds = $coordArray[2] ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

The line gives a `E_NOTICE` ("Notice: Undefined offset: X in Command line code on line 1"). You can either change the error reporting level to not include `E_NOTICE` or just hide disable the error reporting for this particular line with the `@` operator. There is no harm in using `@` here. Unmatched variables will be assigned NULL (in 5 and 7):

```
$coord = "x y";
@list($degrees, $minutes, $seconds) = preg_split("/ /", $coord);
var_dump($degrees, $minutes, $seconds);
```

Gives:

```
string(1) "x"
string(1) "y"
NULL
```

I wouldn't generally recommend it, but to suppress all `E_NOTICE` error notices, you can unset it in the error_reporting setting:

```
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL&~E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: It's not an error it's a notice. It's perfectly legit to hide it. The behavior PHP is giving a notice about is predictable and well understood by the OP and in general..

Comment: if you are able to resolve notice too then why to skip it. Also OP says that his program is shouting about that, means error reporting for notices are on also. So why to skip.why not to resolve?

Comment: Skipping *is* our "resolving" strategy. Just coz it's easy doesn't making wrong; If you're aware of what is causing the notice and exactly what the consequences of ignoring it are -  is in this case, there is nothing to handle, so you explicitly choose to ignore it. It's great that OP has E_NOTICE is on. That does not imply everything reported is something that needs detailed handling!

Answer (score 2):

***You can convert that code like below:-***

```
$d_m_s_array = preg_split("/ /", $coord); 
$degrees = (!empty($d_m_s[0]) ? $d_m_s[0] :0;
$minutes = (!empty($d_m_s[1]) ? $d_m_s[1] :0;
$seconds = (!empty($d_m_s[2]) ? $d_m_s[2] :0;
```

***Note:-***

*Also your original code will generate a notice only (if error reporting is on for that too). Look here:- https://eval.in/707979*

*It will not stop the program execution, **but you can+have-to resolve this notice by the above code***

Answer (score 0):

**Wrap the variably-sized array with [array_pad](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php) as demonstrated below:**

```
list($degrees, $minutes, $seconds) = array_pad( preg_split("/ /", $coord), 3, null);
```

Your intuition is right that you need a *MINIMUM number of elements to return*, and that is exactly what [array_pad](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php) will do for you.